# Mounting windows 10 GPT Partition centos 6

Tags: mount, ntfs

Windows 10 GPT Partition with important data, which I need to mount in centos 6.

Current OS Version

```
[root@dcconnect ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

[root@localhost ~]# parted -l
Model: ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 2      1049kB  538MB   537MB   ext4                                  boot
 3      538MB   5781MB  5243MB  linux-swap(v1)
 4      5781MB  214GB   208GB   ext4
 1      214GB   1000GB  786GB   ntfs            Basic data partition  hidden    

Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label
```

However, I can't seem to be able to mount it:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs'
```

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your kernel version and also what happens if you run `mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `ntfs-3g` and `fuse` :

```
yum -y install ntfs-3g
yum install fuse
modprobe fuse
```

Create a mount point :

```
mkdir /mnt/win
```

Now , run the following command:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/win
```

Comment: This worked without any error, Thanks GAD3R.